# How to retrieve JSON data in same format from mysql, my mysql json data received as string in js?

Tags: angular

How to retrieve JSON data in same format from Mysql, my mysql json data was received as string in js.

I am not able to read the following that I received:

```
menu: "{"Reports": "off", "Dashboard": "on"}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu: "{"Reports": "off", "Dashboard": "on"}"
```

is not a valid string. but the blow on is

```
menu: '{"Reports": "off", "Dashboard": "on"}'
```

and You can convert it to JSON like this

```js
var data = '{"Reports": "off", "Dashboard": "on"}'

parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(parsedData)
```

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript function `JSON.parse(yourdata)` to convert text into a javascript object.

Note: Make sure the text is written in JSON format, or else you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse()` method to convert a valid json string into `json`.

```js
const stringJson = '{"menu":{"reports":"off","Dashboard":"on"}}';
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(stringJson);

console.log(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonObj.menu.Dashboard);
```